# TikZ: Why is "dimension too large"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following TikZ code works fine

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, xscale=0.010, yscale=0.10]  
\draw[magenta,line width=1pt] plot coordinates {  
(1,100.00) (2,99.29) (3,99.14) (4,98.65) (5,99.31)  
(6,99.30) (7,99.70) (8,99.98) (9,98.88) (10,99.77)  
(11,99.75) (12,99.88) (13,99.55) (14,100.15) (15,100.21)  
...  
(561,154.35) (562,154.60) (563,154.38) (564,156.64) (565,156.26)  
(566,157.17) (567,157.78) (568,157.11) (569,154.20) (570,154.05)  
(571,153.74) (572,154.54) (573,153.87) (574,154.95) (575,154.00)  
};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The image is attached.

When I add one more line of data:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, xscale=0.010, yscale=0.10]  
\draw[magenta,line width=1pt] plot coordinates {  
(1,100.00) (2,99.29) (3,99.14) (4,98.65) (5,99.31)  
(6,99.30) (7,99.70) (8,99.98) (9,98.88) (10,99.77)  
(11,99.75) (12,99.88) (13,99.55) (14,100.15) (15,100.21)  
...  
(561,154.35) (562,154.60) (563,154.38) (564,156.64) (565,156.26)  
(566,157.17) (567,157.78) (568,157.11) (569,154.20) (570,154.05)  
(571,153.74) (572,154.54) (573,153.87) (574,154.95) (575,154.00)  
(576,153.82) (577,154.67) (578,155.36) (579,155.63) (580,152.95)  
};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the error message "Dimension too large".
There are 580 pairs of numbers here, 116 lines of numbers.
What dimension has become too large? How do I add more lines?

[image: the image of the lines that printed]

Comment: `580cm = 16502.5892pt > 16383.99999pt = \maxdimen`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `x=0.010cm, y=0.10cm` instead of `xscale=0.010, yscale=0.10`.  The `scale` is only applied after the coordinate has been transformed into `pt` already and that is where you exceed `\maxdimen`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, x=0.010cm, y=0.10cm]  
\draw[magenta,line width=1pt] plot coordinates {  
(1,100.00) (2,99.29) (3,99.14) (4,98.65) (5,99.31)  
(6,99.30) (7,99.70) (8,99.98) (9,98.88) (10,99.77)  
(11,99.75) (12,99.88) (13,99.55) (14,100.15) (15,100.21)  
%...  
(561,154.35) (562,154.60) (563,154.38) (564,156.64) (565,156.26)  
(566,157.17) (567,157.78) (568,157.11) (569,154.20) (570,154.05)  
(571,153.74) (572,154.54) (573,153.87) (574,154.95) (575,154.00)  
(576,153.82) (577,154.67) (578,155.36) (579,155.63) (580,152.95)  
};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

your reach limit of the pure `tikz` image size. i would rather use `pgfplots` and don't bother with `tikzpicture` scaling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\linewidth,
             grid,            % if you like, otherwise delete 
             xmin=0, xmax=600]
\addplot [magenta,line width=1pt] coordinates {
(1,100.00) (2,99.29) (3,99.14) (4,98.65) (5,99.31)
(6,99.30) (7,99.70) (8,99.98) (9,98.88) (10,99.77)
(11,99.75) (12,99.88) (13,99.55) (14,100.15) (15,100.21)
%
(561,154.35) (562,154.60) (563,154.38) (564,156.64) (565,156.26)
(566,157.17) (567,157.78) (568,157.11) (569,154.20) (570,154.05)
(571,153.74) (572,154.54) (573,153.87) (574,154.95) (575,154.00)
(561,154.35) (562,154.60) (563,154.38) (564,156.64) (565,156.26)
%
(575,153.82) (577,154.67) (578,155.36) (579,155.63) (580,152.95)
};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]